# Javascript, toggle-button adding style to element by class

Tags: javascript, html, css, adminlte

I'm using [`AdminLTE`](https://almsaeedstudio.com) template.

There is a `toggle-sidebar button` which do hide and show the `sidebar` by adding and removing `.sidebar-collapse` class in the `body` for each click.

Example:

- by default, it will be `<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">`
- when the `button` clicked once, it will be `<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini sidebar-collapse">`
- when the `button` clicked again, it will back to `<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">`

Now I want to change the `style` (margin-left) of `<section>` with `class="content"` for each `toggle-sidebar` clicked.

Example:

- by default, it will be `<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">` and `<section class="content" style="margin-left:-200px;margin-top:-40px">`
- when the `button` clicked once, it will be `<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini sidebar-collapse">` and `<section class="content" style="margin-left:-380px;margin-top:-40px">`
- when the `button` clicked again, it will back to `<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">`and `<section class="content" style="margin-left:-200px;margin-top:-40px">`

the code:

```
$.AdminLTE.pushMenu = {
    activate: function(a) {
        var b = $.AdminLTE.options.screenSizes;
        $(document).on("click", a, function(a) {
            a.preventDefault(), $(window).width() > b.sm - 1 ? $("body").hasClass("sidebar-collapse") ? $("body").removeClass("sidebar-collapse").trigger("expanded.pushMenu") : $("body").addClass("sidebar-collapse").trigger("collapsed.pushMenu") : $("body").hasClass("sidebar-open") ? $("body").removeClass("sidebar-open").removeClass("sidebar-collapse").trigger("collapsed.pushMenu") : $("body").addClass("sidebar-open").trigger("expanded.pushMenu")
        }), $(".content-wrapper").click(function() {
            $(window).width() <= b.sm - 1 && $("body").hasClass("sidebar-open") && $("body").removeClass("sidebar-open")
        }), ($.AdminLTE.options.sidebarExpandOnHover || $("body").hasClass("fixed") && $("body").hasClass("sidebar-mini")) && this.expandOnHover()
    },
    expandOnHover: function() {
        var a = this,
            b = $.AdminLTE.options.screenSizes.sm - 1;
        $(".main-sidebar").hover(function() {
            $("body").hasClass("sidebar-mini") && $("body").hasClass("sidebar-collapse") && $(window).width() > b && a.expand()
        }, function() {
            $("body").hasClass("sidebar-mini") && $("body").hasClass("sidebar-expanded-on-hover") && $(window).width() > b && a.collapse()
        })
    },
    expand: function() {
        $("body").removeClass("sidebar-collapse").addClass("sidebar-expanded-on-hover")
    },
    collapse: function() {
        $("body").hasClass("sidebar-expanded-on-hover") && $("body").removeClass("sidebar-expanded-on-hover").addClass("sidebar-collapse")
    }
}
```

Please tell me if my question is confusing. I honestly don't understand the code, all the code above is provided by [`AdminLTE`](https://almsaeedstudio.com)

Comment: Is the style in your examples being placed directly on the section or are you just putting it there for the example?

Comment: I want it to be like that (example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use css for your styling. That way you don't need to modify any of your javascript code.

```
/* Sidebar open state */
.content {
   margin-left: -200px;
   margin-top: -40px;
}

/* Sidebar collapsed state */
.sidebar-collapse .content {
   margin-left: -380px;
}
```

The code above is the answer to the original question. The following code is what you need to do what you actually want it to do.

```
/* Sidebar open state */
.content {
   left: 400px;
   position: absolute;
}

/* Sidebar collapsed state */
.sidebar-collapse .content {
   left: 250px;
}
```

There are other possible solutions, but the main reason that `margin-left` doesn't work is because you have items absolutely positioned inside the section. Since they are absolutely positioned, they won't respect margin/padding.

Comment: tried it, but it doesn't work, to be more precise the `sidebar open state`'s margin is works but the `collapsed state` doesn't work

Comment: @EternityNeet Can you add a sample of your html structure and the css that you are trying to your question? Based on what you have in there right now, I can't tell why the selector wouldn't work.

Comment: @EternityNeet any luck?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, here you go [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzxeBLxTvFKBRzJHaGRta25OcUU), the js I post in the question is in `app.min.js` and answer you post is in `template-images.css`

Comment: @EternityNeet I don't have time to look into it any more tonight. If you don't have an answer I'll try to take a look again in the morning. It looks like the styling is applied correctly, but I'm not sure what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: Don't worry, take your time. I want the `<section class="content">` to move according the sidebar (when the left-sidebar is shown, I want the `content` in the center, when the left-sidebar is hidden, I want `it` also move to the left). As it is now, it doesn't move whether the sidebar is shown or hidden

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121337/discussion-between-rdubya-and-eternity-neet).

Comment: this `.content {position: absolute;}` make the `content` move according to the sidebar, I no longer need to adjust the margin for open/close state, thanks anyway